# On what events the "install" hook get triggered

Tags: juju

I am looking at this doc https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-hook-environment which says the install hook is run first, but it does not specify which triggers the "install" hook.
Is "juju deploy" command is the only way to trigger this hook? or are there any other mechanisms?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time a new 'unit' is created the install hook is run, so `deploy`, `add-unit` etc. Its job is to install anything required for the proper operation of the charm on a new machine or container.